# How to use an array as its own indices in Numpy

Tags: python, matrix, numpy, indices

This works in MATLAB:

```
>> p = [1, 0, 2, 4, 3, 6, 5];
>> p(p+1)

ans = 

     0   1   2   3   4   5   6
```

Is there a way to do the same thing in NumPy?  I can't figure out how:

```
>>> p = mat([1, 0, 2, 4, 3, 6, 5])
>>> p[p]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\matrixlib\defmatrix.py", line 305, in __getitem__
    out = N.ndarray.__getitem__(self, index)
IndexError: index (1) out of range (0<=index<0) in dimension 0
>>> p[:,p]
```

The interpreter seems to go into an infinite loop at this point.  This also causes an infinite loop:

```
>>> [p[:,i] for i in p]
```

But this works:

```
>>> [p[:,i] for in range(0,6)]
```

So it is something about using a matrix member as its own indices that causes the problem.  Is this a bug in Python?  Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't know why @katrielalex removed his answer, but it was correct: use an `np.array`, not an `np.matrix`, and your problems disappear. `p = np.array([1, 0, 2, 4, 3, 6, 5]); p[p]` gives the expected result.

Comment: @larsmans Unfortunately it's rather more complicated than that, and I can't understand why. For example, `np.asarray(np.asmatrix(x))[x]` crashes, although `x[x]` doesn't. I think it's a fairly arcane problem due to the wrong type of indexing being chosen, but I'm still thinking.

Comment: @larsmans OK, I see. Ignore me =)

Comment: It seems to be about the data type in the array/matrix, not whether its a matrix or array as such.  `p = np.mat([0, 1, 2, 4, 3, 6, 5]).astype(int); p[0,p]` also does the right thing.

Comment: I've edited the answer to reflect this - once it passes peer review I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only integers can be used as array or matrix indices.  The default type for a matrix initialised like that is float.

You can use a `numpy.array` not a `numpy.matrix`:

```
In [2]: import numpy as np
In [3]: x = np.array([1, 0, 2, 4, 3, 6, 5])
In [4]: x[x]
Out[4]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Or you can explicitly change your matrix to an integer type:

```
In [5]: x = np.matrix(x).astype(int)
In [6]: x[0, x]
Out[7]: matrix([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]])
```

A `numpy.matrix` is a specialised class designed for 2D matrices. In particular, you can't index a 2D matrix with a single integer, because -- well -- it's two dimensional and you need to specify two integers, hence the need for the extra 0 index in the second example.

Comment: Also note that the matrix can be created as an integer matrix directly with `x = np.matrix(x, int)` instead of using `.astype(int)`.